# Kentico 9 Media Library storage options

Tags: kentico

I have a multiple site app that was developed by an outside group, but that I am maintaining / developing additional functionality for.  I am in the process of fleshing out our test environment and found that they had set up the Media Library to be site based. Ok for some items, but we are running into a major duplication of images since alot of them are used for all the sites.

Is there a way to do a combination of global and site-specific folders so that the end users imported media is separated by site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the "Use site-specific subfolders for custom media libraries folder" setting in Settings -> Content -> Media. This will take effect for new media libraries. 
For some sites you can use to use site specific folders and for other you can leave it set to false so a global folder will be used. 
However, then you need to be careful when deleting one of the sites using the global setup - it will delete all the files, so they will be missing for the other sites too.

Comment: Thanks for the insight,  I was thinking that having the files duplicated for multiple sites was a waste of space, and having a global repository would be better, but as you pointed out there is a danger to accidentally deleting the media if we are not careful.

Comment: I guess while I am expanding our test environment I will just have to make sure to leave the user uploaded media on the production server.